# After sending our newsletter out AOL deferrs out email

Tags: linux, email, spam, newsletters

Hi I hope someone can help, a while ago for some reason AOL has taken upon itself to defer all email from ourselves after we send our newsletter.

We get the error code DYN:T1 and then after like 8-12 hours the problem is cleared and all email goes through ok.

Has anyone else had this happen and know what to do.
I've sent through a few reports to them but all I've got so far is a bunch of standard bunf back so nothing of any real help.
As far as we know we have all the standard anti spam things set up so SPF, DKIM and even added on the unsign headers
http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/

Does anyone else have any ideas?
We are thinking about trying to limit the amount sent to AOL in like an hour see if that could help- does anyone have any ideas how to get that to work with mailq?

Thanks for any help/pointers.
Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AOL have [quite a good Postmaster site](http://postmaster.aol.com/) for working through email issues. To rule out blacklisting/greylisting, you can [check your mail server's IP with AOL here](http://postmaster.aol.com/Reputation.php). [Here are their general postmaster guidelines](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.Guidelines.php). AOL have a unique requirement with their [feedback email address loop you should create](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.FeedbackLoop.php).

Comment: If I could +1 this more I would. We took over the email infrastructure from another company (who didn't bother fixing the above issue). After shifting to postfix we then followed the above guidelines. AOL now accepts our mail (there were a few other providers this helped with i.e. BT internet/yahoo mail).

Comment: Hi thanks for your post I've entered a feedback email address thing so hope that will help, I've also used that rep tool and we are neutral. The only thing that we aren't doing on that list is using a different server for our newsletter. Which isn't a problem with other email providers. We do however use a different email address so a donotreply@ for normal email and newsletter@ for our newsletter one

Comment: Just an fyi found a bug in our unsubscribe system if the email address is wrong so might be that!

Comment: Yeah and added to the feedback email so hope we get all this cleared up soon - thanks for your help.